# Free firewall for Windows Server 2003

Tags: windows, firewall, filter, block

We have a Windows Server 2003 R2 Machine here at work that I need to ensure is accessible only from specific set of IP Addresses. The Server is on a LAN and I am aware that one of the possible solutions maybe limit access to the Server's VLAN. However that is not feasible at the moment.

I've been searching for a firewall that could do this, Windows' Firewall is pretty limited and I don't see an option in it to limit incoming data based on Source IP addresses.

Most free firewalls like Comodo and ZoneAlarm don't work on Windows Server.

Any ideas on how to accomplish this would be of great help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

[Windows Firewall comes with Server 2003.  Use it.](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc739696%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)

[The Scope option is probably what you're looking for](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc947832%28v=ws.10%29.aspx).  Allow [blah] on scope [your LAN], deny everything else.

Comment: That didn't work, the server is not on a domain. To create an Inbound Port Rule on Windows Server 2003, i need to use the Group Policy Management feature, which in turn requires that I login using a domain account. Any other ideas?

Comment: The server does not need to be on a domain to manage the firewall - although I see how you came to that conclusion with the second link. You can specify inbound port/program rules in the `Control Panel -> Windows Firewall -> Exceptions` tab, and when adding the exception you can use the `Change Scope` button to choose where the exception applies to.